# Button not showing up in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have configured a tableview in my main storyboard which has a button in the prototype cell. However, when I run it, the tableview cells show up without the button. Here is an image of my storyboard:

[image: tableview]

Can someone explain why it won't show up when I run the program?

Comment: you have set constrain?

Comment: Please check the _delegate_ and _datasource_ have been set or not. Especially the _datasource_.

Comment: add the background color and check once.

Comment: @SagarBhut  Yes, I have set it on the tableview, but not on anything else

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I tried that too and it didn't show up either

Comment: If you added constraint then check it again.

Comment: @Kuldeep do I add constraints to the prototype cell or something else?

Comment: Just look preview on storyboard itself & set constraint accordingly. That much simple question should not be on stack-overflow.

Comment: Show us what you have in `CellForRowAt`.

Answer (score 1):

**Checklist:**

**1.** Set `tableView's` `delegate` and `dataSource` to the `controller`, i.e.

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

**2.** Check if the `height` of `tableViewCell` is not `0`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 200.0 //Actual height of the cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100.0
}
```

**3.** What `constraints` have you added to the `button`? Try adding `centeredHorizontally` and `centeredVertically` `constraints` to the `UIButton`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the height of the table cell. Button is not showing because the height of the cell is small. You must You have to implement the tableView `heightForRowAt indexPath` Method.

Before that Assign `Delegate` and `DtataSource` Method to the tableView.

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
                tableview.delegate = self
                tableview.datasource = self
}
```

If already assign then.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 105
    }
```

Or I think you can also adjust the height from the Size Inspector check the custom height box and provide custom height. And also set proper constraint.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

set background colour of button so that we can check button is created or not. or make sure you can add constraints of UIButton

Answer (score 0):

Just place a break point on your UITableViewDataSource methods. If they are not calling then just go on your storyboard file and set the tableview delegate and datasource in your view controller.

[image]